# Angular Typescript: avoid multiple reference path

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tsd

I am setting Typescript up to an angular 1.5 application. In order to make a TS file be compiled by gulp with no error, I must add the following:

```
///<reference path="../../../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
```

Typings folder is fulled using a node module, "tsd".

So this means so:

- periodicaly I must run "tsd update" to be always up-to-date
- in each TS file I must write the relative path to the TS files... realy annoying

Is there no way to automatize getting the TSD files, and also automatize the insertion for gulp compilation?

Comment: If my answer worked, can you accept it?

Comment: Also tsd is deprecated use typings

Answer (score 0):

Use `exclude` in your `tsconfig.json`. Put the paths that you don't want `tsc` to use there. `tsc` will automatically find all of the typescript files in your project.

Example `tsconfig.json` with `exclude`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry can you please explain me, why excluding the TS files will help gulp to find them?

Comment: @Rolintocour by using exclude ts will automatically find everything not in an excluded folder.

Comment: @Rolintocour in my example ts will find typings/main.d.ts